# How can I write a Haskell function to query a database?

Tags: sqlite, haskell

So I'm trying to write a database layer in Haskell, to interface with a SQLite DB. I'm following instructions from the book Real World Haskell, in the chapter about databases. This is what I have so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.Sqlite3

db = "dev.db"
conn = connectSqlite3 db

getPerson person =
  quickQuery' conn "select name from person where name like ?" [toSql person]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ getPerson "Michael"
```

But I get the error:

```
Could not deduce (IConnection (IO Connection))
     arising from a use of ‘quickQuery'’
   from the context: convertible-1.1.1.0:Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible
                       a SqlValue
     bound by the inferred type of
              getPerson :: convertible-1.1.1.0:Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible
                             a SqlValue =>
                           a -> IO [[SqlValue]]
```

Which as a Haskell beginner I don't really understand. I can put a type annotation on getPerson, but that doesn't really seem to fix it.

Comment: Technically it's not possible to write a *function* that reads from a database. That would be an *action* because it has IO.

Answer (score 8):

This code compiled

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.Sqlite3
import Data.Convertible.Base

db :: String
db = "dev.db"

getPerson :: (Convertible a SqlValue, IConnection conn) => conn -> a -> IO [[SqlValue]]
getPerson conn person =
  quickQuery' conn "select name from person where name like ?" [toSql person]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    conn <- connectSqlite3 db
    person <- getPerson conn "Michael"
    print person
```

`connectSqlite3 :: FilePath -> IO Connection` so value of `conn` should be extract in `IO monad`.

Maybe there is better way to write this using `bind` to pass connection to `quickQuery` but I don't know, I have never use this library, just guessing from the type in `ghci`

Comment: `connectSqlite3 db >>= \conn -> getPerson conn "Michael" >>= print`. I'd say the `do` notation makes it more readable.